# post HTTPRequest of NSDictionary with one NSSet as value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, httprequest, nsset

I have a core data object with a one-to-may relation. So for instance

> ```
> person.mothername
> person.fathername
> person.childrennames <- this is a NSSet
> ```

Now I want to post this at once from the iPhone to our server through one HTTP request. Can this be done?

The code that I use right now for a plain example without NSSet:
Setting the parameters:

```
params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              self.person.mothername, @"mothername",
              self.person.fathername, @"fathername",
              nil];
self.httpRequest = [[HTTPRequest alloc] init];
self.httpRequest.delegate = self;
[self.httpRequest httpPOST:SERVER_POST_PERSON withParams:params];
```

Then the next step (= straightforward):

```
- (BOOL)httpPOST:(NSString *)url withParams:(NSDictionary *)params {

const char *strUrlConst = (const char*)[[self buildParams:params] UTF8String]; 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:strUrlConst length:strlen(strUrlConst)]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    return YES;
}

return NO;
```

}

Then the final method (straightforward?):

```
- (NSString *)buildParams:(NSDictionary *)params {
NSString *builtParams = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];

int i = 0;
for (NSString *key in [params allKeys]) {
    NSString *value = [self escapeString:[params objectForKey:key]];
    if (!value) {
        continue;
    }
    if (!i++) {
        builtParams = [builtParams stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, value]];
    } else {
        builtParams = [builtParams stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, value]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"PARAMS: %@", builtParams);
return builtParams;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSSet`'s `-allObjects` and `+setWithArray:` to convert it to an `NSArray` and back.

Comment: but if the array is part of the rootDictionary. What is the best approach? 2 post commands? Look at the last code snippet in the question. I don't see an easy approach then.

Comment: if you want to keep buildParams as-is and make only one post, you could simply choose a separation character (e.g. newline) for the children.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JSON?
Libraries like SBJson can create a JSON string from an NSDictionary in one line of code (IIRC: [params JSONRepresentation]). It is straightforward to URL encode it by using NSString's percent esacpes method.
On the server side there should be plenty of JSON libraries to choose from for parsing the data.